# Convert string to integer python CGI

Tags: python, database, cgi

I'm stuck on a part of my code where I need to convert the value of a radio button from a string into a int because the function the value goes into takes an integer. When the radio button is selected and the user presses submit, I get a string of that value when I need an integer. I've tried the basic convert tactics in python like int() but I get a TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'. Are there any other ways to convert this value to an int?
For example when I print it out I get ['14'] when I need 14.

My location_table script

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
from A3 import db_access
from area_selection import page
fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
area_id = fs.getlist('area')

if len(area_id)==0:
    page("Exactly 1 selected")
    quit()
try:
    area_id= int(area_id[0])
except Exception as exc:
    page("area id should be valid int: " + str(area_id))
    quit()


location = db_access.get_locations_for_area(area_id)


if not location:
    page("area with id {} does not exist".format(area_id))
    quit()



def page(*messages):
    print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8")
    print("")
    print ('''
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>{}</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style1.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
    '''.format("Areas"))

    def name_key(x):
            return x['location_id']



    print("<form method='get' action='measurement_table.py'>")
    print("<name='area'>")

    print("<table class='grid'>")
    row_template = "<tr>" \
                   "<td>{}</td>" \
                   "<td>{}</td>" \
                   "<td>{}</td>" \
                   "<td>{}</td>" \
                   "</tr>"
    print("<tr><th>Select</th><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Altitude</th></tr>")
    for x in sorted(location, key=name_key):
        location_id = x['location_id']
        name = x['name']
        alt = x['altitude']
        radio = "<input type='radio' name='location_id' value={:.0f}>".format(location_id)
        print(row_template.format(radio,location_id, name, alt ))
    print("</input>")
    print("</table>")
    print("<p>"
          "<input type='submit' value='Get Measurement Information'>"
          "</p>")

    print('''
      </body>
    </html>
''' )

if __name__=="__main__":
    page()
```

my measurements_table script that location_table links to when the user presses submit

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
from A3 import db_access
from area_selection import page
fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

location_id = fs.getlist('location_id')
byte = int(location_id[0])

if len(location_id)==0:
    page("Exactly 1 selected")
    quit()
try:
    area_id= int(location_id[0])
except Exception as exc:
    page("area id should be valid int: " + str(location_id))
    quit()

mea = db_access.get_measurements_for_location(location_id)
```

The problem i'm having from location_table code:

```
    radio = "<input type='radio' name='location_id' value={}>".format
```

And in measurement_table where i'm having the conversion error:

```
mea = db_access.get_measurements_for_location(location_id)
```

The Error:
[In the URL address, you can see the location_id number i'm trying to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNP3t.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a list. Presumably the first item of that list is the value of the selected radio button. You can get the first item of a list using list indexing, like this:

```
location_id = ['14']
location_id = int(location_id[0])
```

If this hasn't helped you then add your CGI code to your question as this is where the problem really is.

Comment: Didn't work. I got the same conversion error. But I added all my CGI code.

Comment: Nevermind got it. That was it. I misunderstood and put in your solution wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @dabrams493 Then show your appreciation by accepting the answer and upvoting it. duh!